# Ssh to server2 via server1 using the credentials on server1

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I have two servers, `server1` and `server2`, and I can connect to `server2` via `server1`:

```
localUser@localMachine $ ssh user1@server1
user1@server1 $ ssh user2@server2
user2@server2 $
```

I can do this in one step using:

```
localUser@localMachine $ ssh -t user1@server1 ssh user2@server2
user2@server2 $
```

I want to be able to simply run `ssh server2` from my local machine and connect directly. I could set up the command above as an alias, but I would prefer to do this through `~/.ssh/config`. The problem is that I need to use the ssh credentials present on server1 when connecting to server2 and I don't want to copy them over to my local machine. This means that the "normal" way I would set this up, by adding the following to my local `~/.ssh/config`, fails:

```
Host server1
    Hostname  server1.example.com
    User      user1

Host server2
    Hostname  server2.example.com
    User      user2
    ProxyJump server1
```

If I now try to connect, I get:

```
$ ssh server2
user2@server2.example.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

This is because I need to use the `~/.ssh/id_rsa_pub` key on `server1` and not the one I have on my local machine. So, how can I set up my local `~/.ssh/config` so that it connects to `server2`, via `server1` and using the credentials present in `server1`?

All machines are Linux boxes, the remotes are running Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 and my local machine is running Arch Linux.

---

I tried the solution given in Hauke's answer and added the following to my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host server1server2
    Hostname server1
    User     user1
    RemoteCommand ssh user2@server2.com
```

This *almost* works! I can now connect to `server2` using `ssh server1server2`, but I don't get a prompt:

```
localUser@localMachine $ ssh server1server2 
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

hostname
server2
```

As you can see above, I am connected to `server2` and can even run commands there, but I am not getting a prompt. I then tried adding `-t -t` to the `ssh` command in the config file:

```
Host server1server2
    Hostname server1
    User     user1
    RemoteCommand ssh -t -t user2@server2.com
```

This got me a prompt, but my shell's initialization files are not being read, and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> kills the `ssh` connection. I need this to behave in the exact same way as if I had done `ssh user2@server1` and then from server1 `ssh user2@server2`. This means that my normal shell initialization files should be read and a Ctrl+C shouldn't kill the session.

Comment: please ckeck this https://serverfault.com/q/337274/482932, it might help

Comment: Thanks, @αғsнιη, I managed to adapt one of the answers there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@αғsнιη pointed me to https://serverfault.com/q/337274/155817 in a comment, and based on that I managed to get it to work using the following lines in my local `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host server2
    Hostname server2.example.com
    User user2
    ProxyCommand ssh -o 'ForwardAgent yes' server1  'ssh-add && nc %h %p'
```

I can now connect directly:

```
$ ssh server2
Identity added: /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

The message above is caused by the `ssh-add` which is adding my identity from server1 to the authentication agent running on server2. That shouldn't be an issue, however.

Comment: [from the source code of the `ssh-add`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/ssh-add.c#L370) it checks if the `q`flag was not passed, then that messages will be shown; if passed, it will quiet the messages; I'm not sure if this will work there or not `ssh-add >/dev/null && nc %h %p`

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two possibilities to have a command be executed on the target via the SSH configuration:

- RemoteCommand
- a separate public key with `command="command"`

So

```
Host server1server2
    Hostname server1
    RemoteCommand ssh user2@server2
```

or

```
Host server1server2
    Hostname server1
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa_force_command
```

And then `ssh server1server2`

Comment: This (using the first example from your answer) _almost_ works (+1) but not quite. I edited my question to show what happens. The second approach just makes `ssh server1server2` connect to `server1`. Is that what you intended? I used `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa` since that's the file I have.

Comment: @terdon The `RemoteCommand ssh -t -t` may not be enough because the terminal may be missing on server1. So does `ssh -t server1server2` work? I haven't found an SSH option which can replace `-t` yet. For the second approach you (more or less) have to create an additional key pair and use the command section in the public key line on server1.